# «Быстрые надежды» — можно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, смысл, словосочетания, лексическая-сочетаемость

> Вот мужество — править в открытое море, зная, что **быстрые надежды** на спасение ложны, путь ведет через страх; и я бы тоже вместе со всеми орал, вставляя в уключины весла, "к берегу" — но почувствовал, что во мне есть малая толика заемного спокойствия Анны, и этого достаточно, чтобы удержаться от паники.
>   [С. Лебедев. Люди августа](https://books.google.ee/books?id=4mlTDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT238&lpg=PT238&dq=%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B&source=bl&ots=Mb7lQi8SeE&sig=ACfU3U1JnYZAfO1BBLZFB7IrkUm87FjsBg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTpqry7bHjAhWQo4sKHUd4AxIQ6AEwBXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B&f=false)

Быстрые надежды — медленные надежды...
Мне словосочетание "не понравилось", во всяком случае, в этом контексте (раньше я с ним не сталкивалась).
Что это такое — *быстрые надежды*? Как вы считаете, грамотно ли так говорить?

Answer (score 1):

Мне это выражение непонятно; возможно, автор хотел сказать "надежды на быстрое/лёгкое спасение" и перестановкой слов попытался украсить свою речь, судя по развесистой фразеологии предложения в целом.

**P.S.** Возможно, в мыслях автора было другое и он подыскивал эпитет именно к "надеждам". "Быстрыми" они *не* бывают, поскольку это слово - о *скорости* движения или изменения. Но можно говорить о *длительности существования* надежд, в таком случае для них подошли бы такие характеристики, как **мимолётные** или **кратковременные**, либо **проблески надежды**.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написала так:

*Вот мужество — править в открытое море, зная, что **быстро вспыхивающие надежды** на спасение ложны….*

**Пояснение**

**Быстрые чувства** – это быстро возникающие чувства, обычный термин в психологии. Например:

**Темпераментом** называется характерная для данного человека совокупность психических особенностей, связанных с эмоциональной возбудимостью, т. е. **быстротой возникновения чувств**, с одной стороны, и силой их — с другой.

Холерик — человек **быстрый**, иногда даже порывистый, с сильными, **быстро загорающимися чувствами**, склонный к бурным эмоциональным реакциям…

https://studopedia.ru/4_96086_obshchaya-harakteristika-temperamenta.html

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

**На самом деле в книге, кажется, совсем другая ситуация, что видно по контексту.**

"Мы вышли в шторм, на лодке заглох мотор. Все существо вопило: к берегу, к берегу, но там был скальный мыс, его нужно было обогнуть и только затем причаливать; чтобы совершить такой маневр, курс – с учетом сноса по ветру – нужно было держать в открытое море. **Вот мужество – править в открытое море, зная, что быстрые надежды на спасение ложны, путь ведет через страх..."**

И тогда всё намного проще (стилистика у автора, как мне кажется, не на высоте, и ничего-то он не украшал и эпитеты тоже не подыскивал).  **Можно было бы написать так:**

"Вот мужество – править в открытое море, зная, что  ***надежда на быстрое спасение ложна, что нужно пройти этот путь через страх..."***

**И никаких надежд там на самом деле не было** — ни вспыхивающих, ни мимолетных, да и синтаксис у автора этакий небрежный.

Comment: Ух, как Вы автора-то "разнесли"!